# How to ground partial run of flexible metal conduit between pvc end points?

Tags: electrical

[image]

The conduit will carry three 2/0 Aluminum cables (2 hots, one neutral) and one 6AWG bare copper grounding conductor from main panel to sub panel.

Edit: Can I use an [Insulated Metallic Grounding Bushing](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Sigma-Electric-ProConnex-2-in-Insulated-Grounding-Bushing-Intermediate-Metal-Conduit-Compatible-Galvanized-Rigid-Conduit-Compatible-Rigid-Metal-Conduit-Compatible-Conduit-Fitting/3389626) inside the pvc junction box and tie the bare copper grounding conductor into it? That should take care of it, right?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, but I doubt you need to ground the conduit,   you're not using it as a grounding conductor, just wire protection.   We'll see what others here have to say.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Any metallic conduit needs to be properly grounded. Period.

Comment: Seems like the best way to do it would be all PVC or all metal.  If you're married to the flex, I would swap the J box and fittings for metal.  If you need the boxes, just do PVC all the way and then your grounding issue is moot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, it's more than just wire protection. Code requires a raceway for individual wires and if that raceway is metal, it has to be grounded. You can use that grounding bushing but run the ground through the lug and on to the panel without splicing it.

Answer (score 4):

### Use metal boxes and done.

The problem is you're trying to mix conduit systems.  Metal conduit is generally expected to be used with metal boxes and the expectation is that grounding will be handled by the boxes, where it *just happens* because of hard metal-metal contact.

Also, if the main and sub are on opposite sides of a stud, feel free to grab a Dremel moto-tool and do some "dental work" on the stud to allow installation of a nipple right through the stud directly connecting the two panels.  I recommend adding a couple of 3/4" pass-thru's while you're at it, to make it easy to move circuits from one panel to the other.  (you only need to reroute hot and neutral).

Comment: Gotta agree here Harp, I was thinking the same thing, I just didn't know the flex conduit needed to be grounded or not.  But agreed:  All metal or all plastic is the way to go.

Comment: If only life was that simple and easy.

Comment: @cryptic0 plastic is not an option in industrial... so that *makes* it simple.

Answer (score 3):

### You're on the right track

Your idea of using an metal grounding bushing with a built-in throat insulator is the right idea; however, the part you linked isn't well suited for your application as you'd need to splice a separate bonding jumper to your existing EGC to use it.

What I'd do instead is use a Bridgeport 386-DC14 or equivalent bushing that has a *lay-in grounding lug* instead of the standard dead-end lug.  This lets you loop the grounding wire through the lay-in lug and continue it on inside the box instead of having to splice a jumper in.

Comment: Can you explain why I cannot simply run the grounding conductor through the grounding lug and tighten it with the bolt? This JB is no more than 10 feet from the sub panel so, it's not too much of an inconvenience to do it this way. I don't see why a jumper would be necessary. [Here is a picture to illustrate](https://imgur.com/undefined)

Comment: @cryptic0 because non-lay-in lugs aren't designed or intended to have conductors fed through them, and may not clamp the conductor correctly if you try it

Comment: I didn't initially believe this, but after getting the lay-in type bushing, it's a day and night difference. This type very firmly holds the bare wire, whereas the thread-in type could not.